# IB API: Checking if in trade or have open order

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers, ib-api

In the interactive brokers API, How do I check if there is already an open order or if I'm in a trade for a specific Contract in python. Can't seem to find an answer online

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/open_orders.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe I found an answer as long as you are trying to get the open orders be printed inside

The openOrder() function was taken straight from the documentation

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *
import threading
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
    EClient.__init__(self, self)

def nextValidId(self, orderId):
    self.nextValidId = orderId
    self.start()


def start(self):
    self.reqAllOpenOrders()
    
def openOrder(self, orderId, contract: Contract, order: Order,
                orderState):
        super().openOrder(orderId, contract, order, orderState)
        print("OpenOrder. PermId: ", order.permId, "ClientId:", order.clientId, " OrderId:", orderId, 
               "Account:", order.account, "Symbol:", contract.symbol, "SecType:", contract.secType,
               "Exchange:", contract.exchange, "Action:", order.action, "OrderType:", order.orderType,
               "TotalQty:", order.totalQuantity, "CashQty:", order.cashQty, 
               "LmtPrice:", order.lmtPrice, "AuxPrice:", order.auxPrice, "Status:", orderState.status)
 

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

# Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(3)
app.disconnect()
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. That will allow me to get the orders but now how would I check if a contract is in the list open orders?

Comment: To my best knowledge, any order that did go through would not show up.